# Making Souk. When do I add these Moroccan spices?

Tags: spices, moroccan-cuisine

I'm making black-eyed peas.  They've been washed, boiled for 2 minutes, set for 1 hour. Now I'm cooking them stovetop on low after bringing to a boil. The spice combination I have is used in making Souk, a Moroccan dish. When do I add the spices?

Comment: can you share the recipe you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot seem to find references to a Moroccan dish named "Souk". Rather, [souk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Souq) is the Arabic word for bazaar or marketplace. Perhaps it refers to the sellers of your spice mix and not a dish to use it in? I will assume you have your hands on a typical Moroccan spice blend such as *ras el hanout*.

In any case, to get the best flavor out of your spices, you need to *bloom* them in oil. Heat oil until shimmering and fry any aromatics you are using. Add the spices, and cook for a few second. Recipes usually tell you to cook "until fragrant", but really, a few seconds should do. It is very easy to burn ground spices. Immediately add the beans and the cooking liquid, simmering until tender.

A good inspiration would be [this recipe](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/voraciously/wp/2019/12/29/indian-spices-make-these-black-eyed-peas-and-mushrooms-taste-like-they-took-hours-not-minutes/) for spiced black-eyed peas. Although it uses Indian spices, the basic technique would be the same.